# Dozer - invoke mapper after converter

Tags: java, dozer

I've got a dozer mapping that returns a User through a custom converter by the parameter. This works as it should, but now this User should be converted to a Official.

I tried to do this by letting the converter return the User and making another dozer xml file to convert the User to the Official. I added this xml file to the dozerfactory, but it doesn't seem to be invoked.

I'm getting: "Exepected Official, actual: User". How could I let the userToOfficial.xml file be invoked?

First dozer file:

```
<mapping>
<class-a>be.someClass</class-a>
<class-b>be.anotherClassWithOfficial</class-b>


<field custom-converter-id="OfficialConverter">
  <a>someString</a>
  <b>official</b>
</field>
```

tried adding, but doesn't work:

```
<b-hint>be.Official</b-hint>
```

the second dozer file (should be invoked after the converter but isn't):

```
<mapping>
<class-a>be.User</class-a>
<class-b>be.Official</class-b>
<field>
  <a>mail</a>
  <b>email</b>
</field>
```

The converter:

```
public class OfficialConverter implements CustomConverter {

/** The ldap local. */
private UserLocal userLocal;

@Override
public Object convert(Object existingDestinationFieldValue, Object sourceFieldValue,
        Class < ? > destinationClass, Class < ? > sourceClass) {
    if (sourceFieldValue == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (sourceFieldValue instanceof String) {
        User user= userLocal
                .getUserByLogin((String) sourceFieldValue);
        return user;

    }
    return null;
}

public UserLocal getUserLocal() {
    return userLocal;
}


public void setUserLocal(UserLocal userLocal) {
    this.userLocal= userLocal;
}
```

}

Comment: Couldn't answer your question properly. The converter seems to return an `User` and how the first and second dozer related. Can you modify your question to give a clear picture?

Comment: @sakura "This works as it should, but now this User should be converted to a Official." The User has to be converted to an Official -> the second dozer file.

Comment: Then instead of introducing a new dozer file, why don't you just modify your customconverter to return an official. I see right now its returning a user.

Comment: Because, then, I would have to manually set the User to Official and then where's the point in using dozer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your customconverter, it seems you are mapping from `String` to `User` and now instead of `User`, you want an object of `Offical`. Right? and you want to automate this `User` to `Offical` conversion using dozer. Right? If yes, then the you need to invoke the new dozer in the custom converter itself using `mapper.map()` method. Your current use-case will not invoke it automatically.